# Ace Editor Custom Syntax

Tags: ace-editor

This is my last attempt before I completely give up. I am trying to use the Ace Editor; so far it has worked really well for existing languages but I do not find the documentation good enough to guide me on how to create a custom syntax highlighter.

I know this is a very broad question, but can anybody point me in the right direction of a decent tutorial or some pointers on how the hell to get this custom highlighter working!?

The Ace Editor tutorial just mentions two files, doesn't really explain the content very well, where to put the files (as the `lib/ace/mode` folder doesn't exist in the pre-packaged version), or how to change the formatting etc.

Appreciate any help.

Comment: it wouldn't be a very broad question if you actually include what you have tried so far and what blocks you. In this current format it should simply be closed

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write your mode in packed mode, then you need to copy one of existing mode files, rename it to mode-mymode.js and use `define("ace/mode/mymode"`, `define("ace/mode/mymode_highlight_rules"` instead of using several files

Comment: Thank you for replying. I know my question really wasn't the most specific, but that's mainly because I don't have a good starting point so didn't know what to ask.

Few questions if you don't mind? 

- I assume my new files; `mymode.js` and `mymode_highlight_rules.js` both go in the `ace-builds/src-noconflict/` directory? 

- I couldn't find a `*_highlight_rules.js` file in that directory. Is there a pre-existing one that exists so I can see how it's set up?

Comment: You add only one file. And add two define functions in it, because in built mode all files are concatenated into one. Check the code in json mode to see how it works, it has both define("ace/mode/json" and define("ace/mode/json_highlight_rules"